# How to create associative multidimensional array from input form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I need to create multidimensional array from input form, because I would like pass information to mysql. I created it, but how can I make it associative one? 
My input:

```
echo "<input type='number' name='hours_to_save[$my_date][$project[$i]]'/>"
```

This is how it print now:

```
array(30) {
    ["2017-05-01"]=>
        array(3) {
            ["kompan"]    => string(1) "2"
            ["5 ogrodow"] => string(1) "3"
            ["karolowo"]  => string(1) "4"
    },
    ...
}
```

But I would like like this:

```
array(30) {
  ["2017-05-01"]=>
        array(3) {
            ["project"] => "kompan" , ["hours"] => string(1) "2"

            ["project"] =>"5 ogrodow" , ["hours"] => string(1) "3"

            ["project"] => "karolowo" , ["hours"] => string(1) "4"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have a key pointing to a key pointing to an array as your desired output, no one can create this array structure for you because it is impossible: `["date"] => "2017-05-01"=> array()`

Comment: @mickmackusa of course, you're right. It can be like this: ` array(30) { ["2017-05-01"] => array(3) { ["project"] => "kompan" ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
$input=array(
    "2017-05-01"=>["kompan"=>"2","5 ogrodow"=>"3","karolowo"=>"4"],
    "2017-05-02"=>["kompan"=>"5","5 ogrodow"=>"6","karolowo"=>"7"]    
);
```

Method #1 ([foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) x2 *recommended)

```
foreach($input as $d=>$a){
    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        $result[$d][]=['project'=>$k,'hours'=>$v];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

This means:

```
$result                         // declare output array
       [$d]                     // use the date values as keys
           []=                  // autoincrement the keys in the subarray
              ['project'=>$k,   // each subarray's 1st element will use 'project' as the key and the input subarray's key as its value
               'hours'=>$v];    // each subarray's 2nd element will use 'hours' as the key and the input subarray's value as its value
```

Method #2 (`foreach()` & [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)-[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) *purely for demonstration)

```
foreach($input as $k=>$a){
    $result[$k]=array_map(function($a,$b){return ['project'=>$a,'hours'=>$b];},array_keys($input[$k]),$input[$k]);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output (regardless of method):

```
array (
  '2017-05-01' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'project' => 'kompan',
      'hours' => '2',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'project' => '5 ogrodow',
      'hours' => '3',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'project' => 'karolowo',
      'hours' => '4',
    ),
  ),
  '2017-05-02' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'project' => 'kompan',
      'hours' => '5',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'project' => '5 ogrodow',
      'hours' => '6',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'project' => 'karolowo',
      'hours' => '7',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Sorry for the code only answer, I'll be back asap to offer a full explanation, and probably check for refinements / alternative methods.  (ran out of time -- Mother's Day and all!)

Comment: Perfect! It works. It's too complicated for me, this is why I didn't sort it out. If you can provide any explanation, I will be very grateful.

Comment: @WojciechB. I'll come back when I wake in the morning and write a simpler version with two loops.  I'll explain everything.

Comment: @WojciechB.  Simple answer and explanation provided.  Comment to me if you have any questions or trouble with this.

Comment: Thank you mate! It's clear now for me. Now, I believe that helpful people exist on forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **foreach** loop for insert to mysql. Foreach will continue to end of the arrays.

```
$newArr = [];
$i=0;
foreach ($yourArray as $key=>$val) {
   $newArr['date'] = $key;
   foreach ($val as $dKey=>$row) {
      $newArr['date'][$i]['project'] = $dKey;
      $newArr['date'][$i]['hours'] = $row;
      $i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, but I have error: `Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplikacja\gra.php on line 120` My 120 line is this line : `$newArr['date'][$i]['project'] = $dKey;`